# Help with bash script only running first two commands after find function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to run the following script

```
 #!/bin/bash         
echo Changing directory permissions
find /home/mike/docker -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
echo Changing file permissions
find /home/mike/docker -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
echo Changing ownership
chown -R mike /home/mike/docker
```

To run it I type `sudo bash runme.sh` ... but it only seems to process the first two commands in the script and then the script seems to end. It definitely seems to run the first find command because it pauses for the appropriate amount of time to run the command.

Here is the output from the console

```
mike@manitoba:~/docker$ sudo bash runme.sh
Changing directory permissions
mike@manitoba:~/docker$
```

Comment: Could you possibly say something more, like how you see that it only runs the first two commands? Does the second `find` get stuck somewhere? Is the `/home/mike/docker` file hierarchy very large? Do you get any error messages? How do you run the script?

Comment: It seems to just get lost after the find command, it seems to still do the first find command and then exits the script?

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: Report status: put something like `echo "Dirs status $?"` after each `find` and `chown` command. Your shell may have the `-e` option set (exit on any command error). You can add the `-x` option to the shebang to show each command executed.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The OP invokes `sudo bash script.sh`, so the shebang is irrelevant.

Comment: I note you used two different names: `script.sh` and `runme.sh`. I recall saving a copy of the script I was working with under a new name or in another directory. This was by mistake. In effect in my text editor I was modifying the new file, but in my shell I kept testing the old file (uparrow, Enter). I was wondering why my changes didn't kick in. Please make sure the script you run is the script you're modifying.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  Good spot. He should insert `set -x` after the shebang instead. I can't figure why asking a question appears preferable to invoking some debug initially.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant "asking a question appears preferable to invoking some debug initially" -- Survivorship bias? You see questions from users who don't debug. You see questions from users who do debug but still need help. You don't see questions from users who do debug, find and fix their errors by themselves; they simply don't need to ask. Debugging may be preferable but we may not see the majority of cases where it was used. E.g. I do debug and I hardly ever ask; and when I ask (I'm more active on SU), I often answer my own question.

Comment: Incidentally, each `find` runs a separate `chmod` process for every single directory or file. If you change the `\;` to '+' in each case, `find` will behave like xargs -- it will give a `chmod` process multiple file args (up to the system limit for command length), and invoke as few processes as is possible.

Comment: re-check that you have the correct script, and include the output of `cat runme.sh` in the question (preferably just before running `sudo bash runme.sh`). If it's the right script, add `echo "$-"` to the start of the script, and run it with `sudo bash -x runme.sh`. And check the exit code with `echo "$?"` afterwards

Comment: There might be a slight benefit also by adding a `-v` option to both the `chmod` and `chown` commands, to explicitly show which entries are having their ownership or modes altered. Then examine whether the `find / chmod` command is exiting prematurely for some reason, leaving some entries unchanged.